# Can the source of an image be changed upon rollover using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, onmouseover, rollover-effect

I have a question on rollover effects using JavaScript.

I have read that image sprites (image with another image on its side) can be used with help of CSS offsetting to achieve basic rollover when `onmouseover` is handled using JS. Have also read about the possibility of changing classes itself using JS (className) to achieve the above effect.

My question is, can I modify the image src itself using JavaScript, to achieve the rollover effect?

A code like this, maybe -

```
document.getElementByID("button1").onmouseover = rolloverFunction;
function rolloverFunction(){
this.src = "button1-image2.png";
}
```

I typed something like this to see if the src of the image can be modified upon rollover, but it is not working. Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. `mouseover` is triggered when hovering in the image, `mouseout` on leaving the image. Using plain ol' JS would yield:

```
<img src="default.png" id="image" alt="">

<script>
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.onmouseover = function () {
    this.src = "rollover.png";
};
image.onmouseout = function () {
    this.src = "default.png";
};
</script>
```

Or using a common function to avoid duplicating the URL:

```
function rollover_effect(img_elm, rollover_src) {
    var default_src = img_elm.src;
    img_elm.onmouseover = function () {
        img_elm.src = rollover_src;
    };
    img_elm.onmouseout = function () {
        img_elm.src = default_src;
    };
}
rollover_effect(document.getElementByID("image"), "rollover.png");
```

Comment: Yes, I just left out the onmouseout part for brevity. My code, I assume, does the same as what you have suggested. I am still getting an error, basically the image on rollover is displayed as a cross; I believe the path is the problem.

Could you please let me know how to mention the full path? I am testing it in my local machine for now, and the image is in the same folder as the webpage and script, and other images.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using Windows then using paths with backslashes in it. In JS, you've to escape such backslashes, so `images\image.png` becomes `images\\image.png`. I recommend you using forward slashes for paths: `images/image.png`. That always works.

Comment: thanks, @Lekensteyn. That worked. The problem was with the backslashes that I had used for the path to the image. Using forward slash worked. THanks again.